# SQL Insert into different tables depending on value from parameter splitter

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have parameter @User with two and more separated by ',' users.
for example:

```
set @User = 'user1,user2,user3'
```

I have #table, for example

```
CREATE TABLE #UserInfo
( 
 CompanyCode nvarchar (10) NOT NULL,
 UserCode nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
 Domain nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
 active int NOT NULL,
)
```

I need to insert data from existing tables into this one, but I need it to be different tables depending on value from parameter splitter so, for example table one will have these values:

```
companycode: ff222
UserCode: user1 
Domain: test
active: 1

companycode: ff224
UserCode: user1 
Domain: test
active: 1
```

table two will have data only for user2:

```
companycode: ff224
UserCode: user2 
Domain: test
active: 1
```

and so on... I tried while loops, tried crying and googling but so far zero rezult...
Thank you for any help!

Comment: will `UNION ALL` of table1 and table2 not help ?

Comment: You mention of `table one` and `table two`. Are these both also temp table ? Also how do you decide which user goes into which table ?

Comment: All I have is parameter with different users. So I need data into different tables depending on this users, the amount of users can be different, so amount of tables could be different too...
and don't need to union them into one table, i need them in different ones...

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, you said you "I need to insert data from existing tables into this one" but then you also said ".. and don't need to union them into one table, i need them in different ones.."
Could you clarify what needs to be done with data after you get it?
-------------------------------------------------
Also, with the tables that have the user data, is there a naming convention used for each one? For example, the table that has user1, would it be named something like 'UserData_User1'?